# MSVC Dependencies vs. References

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have always used the Visual Studio Dependencies option to ensure that, for example, when building my C++ projects, any dependent LIB or DLL projects are also built.  However, I keep hearing people mention 'references' and wondered, with VS 2010 on the horizon, I should be changing how I do this.

Are there any benefits to using references to dependencies or is the former a .NET feature only?  I am currently using VS2008.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I prefer using references since these were introduced for unmanaged C++ in VS 2005. The difference (in unmanaged C++ developer's perspective) is that reference is stored in **.vcproj** file, while project dependencies are stored in **.sln** file.

This difference means that when you reuse your project in different solutions (and I often do) you don't need to redefine the inter-project relationships again.

Visual Studio is smart enough not to depend gravely on the paths of the projects when it establishes the reference relationship.

Comment: I did not know that you could have native C++ projects have references to other native C++ projects.  I think it presents a nicer interface for describing the dependencies than the "Project dependencies..." dialog, too (the only drawback is that you have to open it separately for each project, but that's a very minor quibble).

Comment: +1: References to other projects within the solution are also kinder on version control when there are small changes to the .vcproj file rather than large changes to the .sln file.

Comment: This is a good answer, because it also demonstrates the opposite -- you can have a dependent build order without linking the dependency.  For example, I am creating a DLL which will be loaded on-demand and not loaded immediately with the EXE.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be in VS2008 that a project dependency on a static library would automatically result in the right configuration (Debug|Release) would be linked in.  It looks like VS2010 lost that ability with the move to msbuild.  Sigh.

Comment: It' not lost, you can change these options in properties windows after clicking on reference in Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

'References' are a .NET thing and don't apply to native C++; they are different than dependent projects.  A dependent project in a solution is a project that must be built before (or after depending on which way the dependency goes) another project.

A reference is an assembly that contains types used in the project.  The analogous thing in a native C++ project might be the include files used by a project and the .lib files that get linked in (the native C++ project 'consumes' those items even if they aren't built in another step of the solution).

Comment: -1 References DO apply to native c++ and act pretty much the same as in a managed version. It forces a "dependency" on the project (will always build referenced projects first) and will add the output of the project to the linker. This means that you don't have to fiddle around with library paths & names when linking.